# clustering lines with few words at each line, prefer levenshtein

Tags: python, file, hierarchical-clustering

I have text file with lines the every line has few words, I want to cluster them by lines, and not seperate each line to single word.
I wrote some code but the output is weird.
my code:

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.cluster
import distance

f = open("names.txt", "r")
words = f.read().split(',')
#for line in f:
words = np.asarray(words) #So that indexing with a list will work
lev_similarity = -1*np.array([[distance.levenshtein(w1,w2) for w1 in words] for w2 in words])

affprop = sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation(affinity="precomputed", damping=0.5)
affprop.fit(lev_similarity)
for cluster_id in np.unique(affprop.labels_):
    exemplar = words[affprop.cluster_centers_indices_[cluster_id]]
    cluster = np.unique(words[np.nonzero(affprop.labels_==cluster_id)])
    cluster_str = ", ".join(cluster)
    print(" - *%s:* %s" % (exemplar, cluster_str))
```

output:

```
 - *BRAZEMAX ESTATYS:*  Inc.,  Inc.
BBAZEMAX ESTATES, BRAZEMAX ESTATYS
 - * LTD
Gramkai Books
Bras5emax Estates:*  Jr
John Smith
PC Adelman
Gramkai,  LTD
BOZEMAN Ent.
Gramkat Estates,  LTD
Gramkai Books
Bras5emax Estates
 - * L.T.D.
BOZEMAN Enterprises
BOZERMAN ENTERPRISES
Nadelman:*  Inc.
Bozeman Enterprises
Michele LTD
Gramkat,  L.T.D.
BOZEMAN Enterprises
BOZERMAN ENTERPRISES
Nadelman
```

the file:

```
BRAZEMAX ESTATYS, LTD
Gramkai Books
Bras5emax Estates, L.T.D.
BOZEMAN Enterprises
BOZERMAN ENTERPRISES
Nadelman, Jr
John Smith
PC Adelman
Gramkai, Inc.
Bozeman Enterprises
Michele LTD
Gramkat, Inc.
BBAZEMAX ESTATES, LTD
BOZEMAN Ent.
Gramkat Estates, Inc.
```

what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to remove `\n` characters also. The word are combined with the feed newline character. That's why you see a multiline output.

You may update your code after reading your file:

```
original_file = """BRAZEMAX ESTATYS, LTD
Gramkai Books
Bras5emax Estates, L.T.D.
BOZEMAN Enterprises
BOZERMAN ENTERPRISES
Nadelman, Jr
John Smith
PC Adelman
Gramkai, Inc.
Bozeman Enterprises
Michele LTD
Gramkat, Inc.
BBAZEMAX ESTATES, LTD
BOZEMAN Ent.
Gramkat Estates, Inc."""

original_file
'BRAZEMAX ESTATYS, LTD\nGramkai Books\nBras5emax Estates, L.T.D.\nBOZEMAN Enterprises\nBOZERMAN ENTERPRISES\nNadelman, Jr\nJohn Smith\nPC Adelman\nGramkai, Inc.\nBozeman Enterprises\nMichele LTD\nGramkat, Inc.\nBBAZEMAX ESTATES, LTD\nBOZEMAN Ent.\nGramkat Estates, Inc.'

import re
re.split('[\n,]', original_file)
['BRAZEMAX ESTATYS',
 ' LTD',
 'Gramkai Books',
 'Bras5emax Estates',
 ' L.T.D.',
 'BOZEMAN Enterprises',
 'BOZERMAN ENTERPRISES',
 'Nadelman',
 ' Jr',
 'John Smith',
 'PC Adelman',
 'Gramkai',
 ' Inc.',
 'Bozeman Enterprises',
 'Michele LTD',
 'Gramkat',
 ' Inc.',
 'BBAZEMAX ESTATES',
 ' LTD',
 'BOZEMAN Ent.',
 'Gramkat Estates',
 ' Inc.']
​
```

Now the words are splitted both by new line and commas.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Im new with python and I dont realy understand what to do and how.